# SAML - Triggering Single Logout (SLO) when session times out at the identity provider

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, timeout, logout, identity-provider

Let's say I have Saleforce set up as an Identity Provider with a session timeout of 15 minutes. I set up a connected app with SAML and SLO. I use SSO to access a connected app and start working only on the other application for 30 minutes. My questions:

1. Will my Salesforce session time out after 15 minutes
2. If it does, will I be logged out of the external application

I didn't manage to find any documentation on this. I know that if you purposely logout of Salesforce all connected app sessions will be terminated, but not sure what happens in a session time out.

Answer (score 0):

> Will my Salesforce session time out after 15 minutes

Yes

> If it does, will I be logged out of the external application

No, see identigral's comment on this answer

An important thing to note about the timeout value is that you shouldn't necessarily expect perfect timing due to how the system checks for activity as noted in the description of `timeout value` [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_sessions.htm&type=5)

> The last active session time value isn’t updated until halfway through
> the timeout period. So if you have a 30-minute timeout, the system
> checks for activity when 15 minutes have passed. If you update a
> record after 20 minutes, your timeout resets because it’s 5 minutes
> after the active session time is checked. In that scenario, you have
> another 30 minutes before log out occurs, for a total of 50 minutes.
> But if you update a record after 10 minutes, logout occurs 20 minutes
> later (30 minutes total) because there was no activity in the past 15
> minutes.

The help doc concerning [managing session policies](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=connected_app_manage_session_policies.htm&type=5) also states the following for understanding which timeout policies will affect your connected app if you don't set one on the connected app itself:

> You can control how long a user’s session lasts by setting the timeout
> value for the connected app, user profile, or org’s session settings
> (in that order). If you don’t set a value or you select None (the
> default), Salesforce uses the timeout value in the user’s profile. If
> the user’s profile doesn’t specify a timeout value, Salesforce uses
> the timeout value in the org’s Session Settings.

Comment: The answer to second question is no - SLO isn't triggered by a session expiration even when `Force logout on session timeout` is true.